# What is the pdf of Z = XY?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint pdf $f_{XY}(x,y)$. Determine the pdf of $Z = XY$

---

My friend said he solved this using a Jacobian matrix. I'm not well versed  in that topic so I tried solving it the way I solved similar problems.

Here is the hyperbola formed when $Z = 2$:

[image]

From this figure, I can separate my original probability into the probability that $X > 0$ and the probability that $X < 0$:

$$
P(Z\leq z)=P(XY\leq z)=
P(Y\leq \frac{z}{X}\big|X>0)P(X>0)+P(Y\geq \frac{z}{X}\big|X<0)P(X<0)=
$$
$$
 \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\frac{z}{x}}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx +  \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}\int\limits_{\frac{z}{x}}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx
$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Do I need to take partial derivatives of each integral because it is a joint pdf? I'm trying to solve this problem using this CDF -> to PDF method because that conceptually makes sense to me. Is it possible to solve it this way?

Comment: Are you familiar with change of variables for integration? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: Yes, but I'm not actually given an equation for a pdf in this problem so I'm not sure what the integrand needs to be in Step 2.

Comment: If you notice in the solution you posted, they don't evaluate the integral. They change variables, and state the solution in terms of an integral that removes the dependence on `w` and leaves a function of `z`. That's the idea here. I can write it out more explicitly if you want. PS the jacobian (really the determinant of the jacobian matrix) is just needed to change variables. No magic to it, I promise

Comment: Differentiate your expressions with respect to $z$ to get $f_Z$. This will give you an expression for $f_Z$ when $z>0$

Comment: Hi Mathew, could you post your answer? I tried differentiating with respect to z but I'm not getting a result with a w in it

Answer (score 1):

Define:

$$
w = x, \quad z / w = y
$$

Then

$$
\iint_{\Omega} f_{XY}(x,y) \, dx\, dy= \iint_{\Phi(\Omega)} f_{XY}(w, z/w) \left|J\right| \, dz\, dw,
$$

where $\Phi(z,w) = \left(x(z,w), y(z,w)\right)$ and $J = D\Phi$ is the Jacobian matrix:

$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial w} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial w}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
w^{-1} & -zw^{-2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This gives us an expression for the joint probability density:

$$f_{ZW}(z,w) = f_{XY}(w,z/w)\left|J\right|$$

The marginal distribution is the answer you want:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{Z}(z) & = \int_\mathbb{R} f_{ZW}(z,w) \, dw \\
 & = \int_\mathbb{R} f_{XY}(w, z/w) \left|J\right| \,dw \\
 & = \int_\mathbb{R} -\frac{z}{w^2}f_{XY}(w, z/w) \,dw, 
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: how do you relate the change of variable formula here to the calculus one on the wiki page you cited in the comments?

Comment: They should be the same. Are they not? The section "Substitution for multiple variables" should have an expression in terms of the jacobian.

Comment: With the calculus one, I would expect one of the two integrals in the identity to have dummies w,z and the other to have dummies x,y

Comment: Oh I think I see what you mean. I'll add some more detail when I get up tomorrow. I can explain, i think. My notation is sloppy

Comment: Is this what you were thinking @Hasse1987 (see changes)

Comment: Yes clear, thanks. Though don't you want $\Phi^{-1}(\Omega)$ in the limit of integration on the RHS?